# Advanced date sorting in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, date-time

I'm currently working on a project that requires looking at temperatures measured once every hour. As with all instruments there have been hours/days where the instruments haven't been measuring.
 What I want to do is to calculate an average temperature for each day, even though each day does not consists of 24 rows. Is this possible? The format of the date is shown in the link.

[image: [1]]

Comment: Can you provide us with an example where we can see the missing values and calculated average for this example?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach, without any formula fuss, would be to create a pivot table. Pull the date/time field into the rows area and the temperature field into the values area and set it to "average" .

[image]

Right click any value in the values area then select **Summarize values by > Average**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your Excel Version you can use

- in Excel 2016 the [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function
- or previously (Excel 2010/2013) the same tool as free MS add-In called [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (Excel 2010/2013)

Depending where your temperature records are saved (csv file or Excel table), you import them in the UI.
Then you split the date column into two (date + time)
and finally group by date the temperature column (average). You got so a new table.

In the example, I assume thate your datas are saved in two column:

| Date | Temperature |

The generated Code from the Get & Transform UI will look like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle2"]}[Content],
    #"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type text}, {"Temperature", type number}}),
    #"Split column by delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Change Type", "Date", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Date.1", "Date.2"}),
    #"Change Type 1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split column by delimiter",{{"Date.1", type date}, {"Date.2", type number}}),
    #"Group rows" = Table.Group(#"Change Type 1", {"Date.1"}, {{"avg temperature", each List.Average([Temperature]), type number}})
in
    #"Group rows"
```

Comment: Power Query is great at transforming data and I love it to bits. But in this case, a simple pivot table will do nicely.

Comment: you are right a pivot is more straightforward. Depending where the raw datas are stored, then the "Get" step could be helpfull. The Transform can then help for parsing the date column if not recognized by Excel.